# pamentgateway in php

Tags: php, payment-gateway

i would like to learn the Paymentgateway [interaction with bank and make transaction] in PHP . Please guide me a website to go through .. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at something like the following: [Paypal API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_overview), [Google Checkout API](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/), [Amazon Payments API](http://aws.amazon.com/fps/)

Comment: beware, paypal API for developers has many glitches and requires you to create a new (testing) account. also, many of your local banks would likely offer their own api, so check with them.